Malware analysis windows file
During malware analysis ,  I was examining the sample in the cloud-service , but the clipboard copy was working from cloud machine to my local system.
I believe there will be problem will happen when the malware is based on the window clipboard .
What is the remediation for that?

That "clipboard copy from cloud machine to local system" - is what you are talking about the RDP clipboard synchronization feature?
